# CSV to 2D array but Split function throws a NullPointerException

Tags: c#, .net, csv, multidimensional-array, webforms

I was trying to put loop through and put **CSV to 2D array.**

My app **crashes** due to `var tokens = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');` It throws a **NullPointerException**. How can I fix this?

Below is my whole method named **csvToArray**:

```
public string[,] csvToArray (string filePath)
        {
            int col = colCount(filePath);
            int row = rowCount(filePath);
            string line;

            string[,] data = new string[col, row];

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
                {
                    var tokens = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');

                    for (int j = 0; j < row; j++)
                    {

                        data[i, j] = tokens[j];
                    }
                }
            }
            return data;
        }
```

What does not make sense is that it finished the whole loop. The variables below the exception **have the values that they were supposed to have**.
[image]

Comment: I think row and column for loops should be swaped

Comment: Try adding a simple `if (sr != null)` check before `var tokens = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');`. Or optionally a `var line = sr.ReadLine()` and `if (sr != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))`.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL My CSV file has blank values.. Would that contribute to the problem of the Split?

Comment: That would ensure you don't throw exceptions IF there are any blank values. Also, since the exception occurred on the Split line, I think it is due to you trying to Split blank values. In any case, the `if` condition will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use first `for` loop for row and then inner loop for column.

```
public static string[,] csvToArray(string filePath)
    {
        int col = colCount(filePath);
        int row = rowCount(filePath);
        string line;

        string[,] data = new string[row, col];

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                var tokens = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');

                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
                {

                    data[i, j] = tokens[j];
                }
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

In your code you are doing `null.Split()`, that is why it giving you exception.

If you want to insert `0` in each cell for a blank row, then you can implement the following code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                string content = sr.ReadLine();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
                {
                    var tokens = content.Split(',');

                    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
                    {

                        data[i, j] = tokens[j];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
                    {

                        data[i, j] = "0";
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I've checked also but the `filePath` is really correct and working. I wonder why the `sr` is `NULL`.

Comment: U must have an empty line. So what do u want if you have empty line in CSV? do u want to insert a blank array in 2D array, or just want to ignore that line.?

Comment: How can I insert '0' for the empty lines? I have to average all columns after it so inserting '0' on blank spaces makes sense.

Comment: I started implementing according to you comment :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133792/discussion-between-vivek-nuna-and-jpaulpunzalan).

Answer (score 1):

Lets first analyse errors in your example.

1) Why do you event need to know length of row and columns in the beggining? It is overhead.

2) Row and columns in your loop is invalid.

3) This exception throws in your example because your reached EOF.

So, here is better way to read csv to 2D matrix:

```
public int[][] csvToArray (string filePath)
        {
            string line = null;
            var result = new List<int[]>();
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)) continue;
                    result.Add(sr.Split(',').Select(x=> string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x) ? 0 : int.Parse(x)).ToArray());
                }
            }
            return result.ToArray();
        }
```

Then you can just check your matrix for consistency.
At least, this way you won't open your file three times and protected from counting errors.

Comment: How can I insert "0" in the empty values? so that the task after it would be easier which is getting the averages of each column.